# Init std::map defined in class

Tags: c++, std, stdmap

Hi guys I've been searching out, how to init this map, but I could not found it.

```
//Header
class EntityManager
{
    //Other class code
    private:
    std::map<Entity*, EngineEntity*> _gEntMap;
    //Other class code
}
//Source
EntityManager::EntityManager()
{
    //How to init map?
}
```

I ask this because when i try to add things in this map, gets me an error because it's not intialized.

Comment: It should be automatically default-initialized by the `EntityManager` constructor.

Comment: [The reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) might help. Check the initializer list constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's an object of `std::map` it should be automatically initialized and ready to use. If you're getting an error when trying to insert things into the map it's because you're doing it wrong, not because the map isn't initialized.

Example of inserting in your specific map:

```
_gEntMap.insert(std::make_pair(PointerToEntity, PointerToEngineEntity));
```

Comment: Thank you, and how I should insert things to that map, in vector class we have push_back, but for map I don't know how, Thank you

Comment: Your `map` consists of `Entity*, EngineEntity*` so a way would be : `_gEntMap.insert(std::make_pair(PointerToEntity, PointerToEngineEntity));`

Comment: Or just `_gEntMap[PointerToEntity] = PointerToEngineEntitiy;`

Comment: @TartanLlama That may override existing elements and he asked for inserting specifically.

Comment: Thats how doesn't work, using gEntMap[Entity*] = EngineEntity*, but the function insert works perfectly THANK YOU